# Backup MySQL via Java

Tags: java, mysql

I am making a program to automatically backup a MySQL database from within java using MysqlDump. I want to get the file created and zip it. However, I am having an issue with the MySQLDump.

I am using the following to create a MySQLDump:

```
Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                "mysqldump -u "+user+" --password='"+password+"' "+database+" > /root/moltres/backups/sql/"+database+".sql"
                );
```

I have a while loop after this which remains in the loop if `pr.isAlive()`. I thought this would work, but it appears that when the command is executed, the process instantly becomes no longer alive. I could make the thread sleep, but for how long? How can I make the same SQL backup, but detect when the mysqldump command has completed?

Answer (score 0):

The command is exiting immediately all right. It is *failing*, because the redirection isn't being understood by `mysqldump`.

This is not how you use `Process`. You need to:

1. Use `ProcessBuilder`.
2. Merge the output and error streams.
3. Add `sh -c` or `cmd /c` as appropriate to the beginning of the command line to handle the redirection.
4. Start the process.
5. Consume the output stream and log it, reading until end of stream.
6. Call `Process.waitFor()`.
7. Get the process's exit code and log that.

Why you're using Java for this at all is a mystery. It's just a shell script. Indeed you can get MySQL to schedule its own backups automatically, without even needing a  script.